# perl assign variables to an array with relationship

Tags: perl, perlscript

Please advice how to pass 3 variables in an array with relation.

```
@item = ($a , $b , $c);
@record = push(@array, @item);
```

I want to assign value in a @array so that if I look for any instance I should get value of all a,b,c.

Is there any way apart from comma to assign a value in array. like $a:$b:$c or $a>$b>$c
I need this because i am want to grep 1 record(a) and get (a:b:c)

```
@array1 = grep(!/$a/, @array);

expected output should be a:b:c
```

Thanks,

Comment: How do you mean the expected output should be "a:b:c"? Executing a `grep` and assigning its return value to an `@array` won't output anything.

Comment: Actually I am pushing 3 different variables to an array.
and I want if any one of the match I want to remove all 3 from array.

for example if there are :

abc 
def
zte
fgi
adf

I want to remove abc and adf as i am grepping for a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not very clear. Maybe you should rephrase it.
However, I understand you want an array with groups of three elements.

You might want to use array references.

```
@item = ($a , $b , $c);
push(@array, \@item);
```

or

```
$item = [$a , $b , $c];
push(@array, $item);
```

Also, `push`won't return an array as you expect. Perldoc says:

> Returns the number of elements in the array following the completed
>   "push".

Now if you want to filter these groups of three elements, you can do something like that:

```
my @output = ();
L1: foreach ( @array ){
    L2: foreach( @$_ ){
        next L1 if $_ eq $a; 
    }
    push @output, $_;
}
```

Please note that if you want an exact match you should use the `eq` operator instead of a regex...

Comment: Thanks for the response pierre ..Now if I grep in @array what output I will get as I am expecting abc